# Creating replication between SQL Server 2000 (publisher) and SQL Server 2008 (subscriber)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

I have old database server as SQL Server 2000 whose data has to be periodically updated to the SQL Server 2008 server (may be one time per day). So I have planned to use the replication. First I have created distribution database in SQL Server 2000 & added the new database as publisher.

But when I created the subscriber in SQL Server 2008 & connects to SQL Server 2000 then the publisher doesn't appear in the list. What could be the reason, I am using SQL Server 2008 express edition or if any one could point out to the step by step guide for setting up replication between SQL Server 2000 and 2008? I have used the wizard in SQL Server 2000 for creating distribution & publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed versions are supported, but:

- Distributor version must always be equal or newer than Publisher
- Subscribers for transactional replication can be within 2 versions newer/older of Publisher
- Subscribers for merge replication must be equal or older than Publisher