# Migration from SQL Server 2000 to 2012 without Outage

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project which is migrating some legacy SQL Server 2000 instances to SQL Server 2012. As you read word legacy, these databases are used by some VB based desktop applications. It has around 4000+ users and application is rated GOLD (means it has to be up 24x7)

Summary again

- Desktop exe Installed VB applications -> SQL Server 2000

Target State

- Desktop exe Installed VB applications -> SQL Server 2012

Application uses a config file that contains SQL Server details that it connects to. So once data move to new SQL Server, this config file needs to be changed with new server details.

I have been told that SQL Server 2000 can't migrate directly. It should first go to SQL Server 2008 and then SQL Server 2012. Please correct if this is not right understanding?

My problem is around Implementation Plan for this task in production. I can't move all users in one go means I would be migrating 100 users first and then few other hundreds and finally all left. Which means some users might start using SQL Server 2012 while other still working with SQL Server 2000. The reason I don't want everything in one go because it's too risky in case of any glitch and because application has to be up 24x7 it's not possible to bring down the applications and update config files on each user's desktop.

But if I allow 2000 and 2012 running together (say 1 week until all users move), it will make these databases out of sync and I don't think they can be merged later because both databases may be having same primary keys assigned to different data.

I can't bring the application down and take 4 hours outage to allow all users move to new databases in one shot because application has to be up 24x7.

Can any one recommend any approach that generally companies take to migrate SQL Server without outage like I stated above with keeping data consistency?

Comment: There really isn't any way around taking an outage due to the need to have an intermediary update as you've correctly stated it isn't possible to go from 2000->2012 directly.

Comment: I am Ok to take outage for that small time to migrate SQL data from 2000 to 2012 (via 2008). But what do you think how should I manage if I don't want to move all users in one go as my production team wants to see how solution work for couple of days with some users and then move rest of all later.

Comment: This is really more of a [sf] question than a [so] question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle this is to create a new 2012 instance and create a database from a restore of the 2000 database.  Then have replication between the 2 databases so that changes in either database will be published to the other that way your primary keys stay in sync.  You will have to be down for a short period where you do the backup and restore to move all the data but assuming the 2 servers are co-located then it should only be a matter of minutes.  Then once all your users have been migrated just turn off the 2000 server.

Comment: Are you talking about Database based Replication or File Storage Replication? If it's Database Replication, you means it's possible to put replication strategy between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2012?

Comment: I am talking about database based replication.  Yes it's possible to have a replication strategy between different versions.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009212/creating-replication-between-sql-server-2000-publisher-and-sql-server-2008-su

Comment: Thanks Avitus. About migration of Data, do you know if it's absolutely necessary to go via 2008?

Comment: @RohitGoyal: **YES** - you **cannot** restore a SQL Server 2000 backup on a SQL Server 2012 instance. The 2000 version is just **too old** for this ....